# Simple shear force calculation for the flat face of a container of fluid

Tags: forces, fluid-statics

I'm trying to model a situation I'm working with, to estimate roughly the forces that I have to resist. But my physics is rusty and I'm not 100% sure how to get it right.

The model shows a **side view** of a **1.3m high** vertical thin sheet (assumed infinitely thin and infinitely rigid as usual for simplicity) that is some width **w** (the width doesn't matter much, as it scales linearly, so we can assume w = 1 metre).  It holds back 1.3m of a liquid with density **D kg/m<sup>3</sup>**. The sheet is held in place by forces **F1** and **F2** along its top and bottom edges, both in units of **Newtons per linear metre**.

[image]

I'm trying to calculate F1 and F2, and specifically a rough idea of the shear force per metre that needs to be resisted/applied at F2, to prevent the edge sliding.  (Leaks at the sealed left and right edges can be ignored). But I can't be sure I remember how, since unlike many force diagrams, there's a greater pressure at the bottom than the top edge.

How is it calculated?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go on about solving this problem:

The labels I'll be using are $F_1$ and $F_2$ for the forces on your sketch, $F = F_1+F_2$, $\rho=1000 \frac{kg}{m^3}$ for water density, $h$ for height, $h_0=1.3m$ for total height $g$ for gravity acceleration and $W$ for width (which in this case is 1m).

First we must calculate the entire force needed to hold the water.

$$
dF = \rho ghdS = \rho g h W dh\\
F = \rho g W \int_0^{h} hdh = \frac{1}{2}\rho g W h^2
$$

In our case $h=h_0$. The we must calculate the height of the average force exerted on the board.

$$
\overline F = \frac{1}{h_0} \frac{1}{2}\rho g W \int_0^{h_0}h^2 dh = \frac{1}{6}\rho g W h_0^2 \\
$$

From that equation follows that the height of the average force is $h=\frac{h_0}{\sqrt{3}}$. Now we must solve the following system of equations:

$$
F_1 + F_2 = F \\
F_1 \frac{h_0}{\sqrt{3}}=F_2 h_0\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

The first equation tells us that the total force on system must be 0, and the second equation tells us that the torque must be 0.

If we solve system for $F_1$ and $F_2$ we get:

$$
F_2 = \frac{3 F}{2+\sqrt{3}} \\
F_1 = \frac{F(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2+\sqrt{3}}
$$
Where F equals total force needed to hold the water.

Comment: Some of that sounds familiar, thanks! I'm rusty, couldn't remember how to handle the varying pressure and height. But one thing, can you check because I have a trace of a memory triggered by that working, that the centre of pressure in a dam is 1/3 of the way up not 1/sqrt(3)??? But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Stilez Yes, sorry I made a miscalculation computing center of pressure. My bad. You are correct the true CoP is 1/3 from bottom. If you want to see how we come to that result this might help you: [link](http://people.exeter.ac.uk/TWDavies/solid%20mechanics/Hydrostatic%20Force%20on%20a%20submerged%20vertical%20surface_files/image006.jpg)